# How to send pushes with python using CleverTap API?

Tags: python, api, push-notification, clevertap

I am in the process of migrating my Parse push notification data to CleverTap. The problem that I am having is that the [documentation](https://support.clevertap.com/server/downloading-profiles-and-actions/) is not very good about it and the [examples](https://github.com/CleverTap/clevertap-server-api-examples) that they give don't cover push notifications.

Anyone have an example of how to send pushes with CleverTap API using Python or at least evidence that this is possible?

Comment: Did you figure this out?

Comment: Nope, I decided for OneSignal instead

Comment: They updated their doc. [https://support.clevertap.com/server/send-notifications/push/](https://support.clevertap.com/server/send-notifications/push/).

Answer (score -1):

The documentation now covers how to migrate your Parse installations to CleverTap. For example, say we are creating a push notification to be sent to users subscribed to the "yankees" and "mets" channels.

```
curl -H "Content-Type:application/json"
 -H "X-CleverTap-Account-ID: Your CleverTap Account ID"
 -H "X-CleverTap-Passcode: Your CleverTap Account Passcode"
 --data "@payload"
 "https://api.clevertap.com/1/targets/create.json"
```

Payload

```
"name": "My API Campaign",
"where": {
    "common_profile_prop": {
        "profile_fields": [
            {
                "name": "channels",
                "value": ["yankees", "mets"]
            }
        ]
    }
},
"content":{
    "title": "Breaking News",
    "body": "Yankees Win 5-4",
    "platform_specific": {
        "ios": {
            "deep_link": "example.com",
            "sound_file": "example.caf",
            "category": "reactive",
            "badge_count": 1,
            "key": "value_ios"
        },
        "android": {
            "background_image": "http://example.jpg",
            "default_sound": true,
            "deep_link": "example.com",
            "key": "value_android"
        }
    }
},
"devices": [
    "android",
    "ios",
],
"when": "now"
}
```

Response

```
{
"status": "success",
"id": 1457433898,
"estimates": {
    "android": 90,
    "ios": 300
}
}
```

Hope this helps. More documentation can be found here -
https://github.com/CleverTap/parse-migrate

Comment: would this be better as a comment than an answer?  generally people want a full explanation from an answer, not just a link to a full explanation.

Comment: How to send image in notification tray in ios devices? With android I am able  to achieve it with image url